# Flexbox can't use 'justify-content' horizontally in Reactive.js

Tags: reactjs, flexbox

I need some help with flexbox. I'm not able to evenly distribute all components in a row with 'justify-content' - the components only stay in a column. It seems that React does not consider the 2 components that were generated from props - it treats all as just one component.

App.js

```
    const App=()=> {
        return(
            <>
                <Header />
                <div className="containerHeader">
                    <h1>RECEIVE THE BEST DENTAL TREATMENT TO AVOID CROOKED-TEETH PROBLEM</h1>
                    <h2>We will give you the accurate assessment to find out which braces best suit you.</h2>
                </div>
                {Data.map((values)=>{
                    return(
                        <>
                            <Meeting 
                                key={values.id}
                                imgsrc={values.imgsrc}
                                text={values.text}
                            />
                        </>
                    )
                })}
            </>
        );
    };
```

Meeting.js

```
     const Meeting=(props)=> {
      return(
            <div className="containerMeeting">
                <div className="containerCard">
                    <img src={props.imgsrc} alt="Girl" />
                    <p>{props.text}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
      );
   };
```

Meeting.css

```
    .containerMeeting {
        padding: 0px 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

MeetingData.js

```
const Data=[
    {
        id:1,
        imgsrc:"../Images/1.jpg ",
        text:"Well-aligned teeth and fresher breath always leave a good impression when meeting a person for the first time."
    },
    {
        id:2,
        imgsrc:"../Images/2.jpg ",
        text:"Even in a job interview your smile can lead to a favourable situation"
    }
]

export default Data;
```

I hope that React considers the 2 components and distribute them horizontally.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong you want the `img` and `p` aligned in a row (side by side)?

Comment: No, I don't want 'img' and 'p' aligned in a row. I want each 'containerCard' div to be aligned in a row. Inside 'containerMeeting' I have just one 'containerCard', but after props is applied, two compents will be displayed(see in MeetingData.js that I have two elements inside 'Data' object. I'm using props to not have to write two div inside 'containerMeeting', but it seems that React only recognize one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*It seems that React does not consider the 2 components that were generated from props*", there is only one `containerCard`element inside the `containerMeeting` element. Thus nothing to align in a row.

When you `map` over `Data` what it will **return** will look like this

```js
<div className="containerMeeting">
  <div className="containerCard">
    <img src="../Images/1.jpg " alt="Girl" />
    <p>Well-aligned teeth and fresher breath always leave a good impression when meeting a person for the first time.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div className="containerMeeting">
  <div className="containerCard">
    <img src="../Images/2.jpg " alt="Girl" />
    <p>Even in a job interview your smile can lead to a favourable situation</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to make your `containerCard` elements appear in a row you should move the `containerMeeting` element out of the `Meeting` component and use it to surround `Data.map`

```js
const Meeting = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="containerCard">
      <img src={props.imgsrc} alt="Girl" />
      <p>{props.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
<div className="containerMeeting">
  {Data.map((values) => {
    return (
      <Meeting key={values.id} imgsrc={values.imgsrc} text={values.text} />
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, RubenSmn, very much! This change really solved my problem. You rock, man!!

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted for when other people in the future have the same problem

Comment: As I am new here, I was looking for the button, but I have just found it. Thanks again!